# How to pass child element to parent in React

Tags: reactjs

How can i pass child element to parent element and then render it using React?

Example of my code:

```js
let persons = [{name: 'Bill', age: '25'}, {name: 'John', age: '35'}]; // etc etc


function showPersons(data) {
    data = persons;
    let fatherDiv = <div></div>;
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let person = <span>Name: {data[i].name}, age: {data[i].age}</span>
        fatherDiv.appendChild(person); //here's the error
    }
    ReactDOM.render(fatherDiv, document.getElementById('app'));
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <button onClick={showPersons}>Show</button>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

PS im new to React

Comment: What do you mean when you say element? Component? Data? If you mean component, than you shouldn't do that. If you think Data they you have couple of methods. 1) pass useState hook to child, and call setState inside child component. 2) use some state container like Redux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by going through the basic concepts of the *React* library and how the DOM elements should be manipulated with it.

A good starter would be [the official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) which goes step by step through the different concepts one at a time.

In *React*, you should not be manipulating the DOM element as you are doing with `appendChild`, instead, you should be creating new, or updating, `ReactElement` types (either programmatically through the Javascript API or using JSX ~ you can read more on both within the linked documentation).

Here down how you can achieve the same behavior, i.e. updating your rendered content, though the *React* way:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default function App() {

  const persons = [{ name: "Bill", age: "25" }, { name: "John", age: "35" }];

  const showPersons = () => {
    const fatherDiv = persons.map(data => (
      <span>
        Name: {data.name}, age: {data.age}
        <br />
      </span>
    ));
    ReactDOM.render(fatherDiv, document.getElementById("app"));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={showPersons}>Show</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Meanwhile, this should not be the way to go with updating rendered content and generally you would have to only call the `ReactDOM#render` once upon root component mounting. The desired behavior can be achieved using *React* component's **state**:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default function App() {
  // this is your data store (can also be any external data source
  const persons = [{ name: "Bill", age: "25" }, { name: "John", age: "35" }];

  // this is your component state, you can think of it as the live data within the component which may change along the lifecycle of the component
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  // this is the function that will be called to show persons by *just updating the state* and React will take care of re-rendering the component for us
  const showPersons = () => {
    setData(persons);
  };

  // this is the function that will be called to hide persons showed previously by *just updating the state as well* and React will take care once again of re-rendering the component for us
  const hidePersons = () => {
    setData([]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={showPersons}>Show</button>
      <button onClick={hidePersons}>Hide</button>
      <div id="content">
        {data.map(person => (
          <span>
            Name: {person.name}, age: {person.age}
            <br />
          </span>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Here you can check [a live demonstration](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8jsccn) of state manipulation.

Comment: You are welcome, hope it helps setting the start lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
function showPersons() {
  const result = persons.map((person, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
      <span>
        Name: {person.name}, age: {person.age}
      </span>
    </div>
  ));

  ReactDOM.render(result, document.getElementById("root"));
}
```

Visit to see full code [Working solution live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-beaver-d4oe3?file=/src/index.js)